# Quickblox JS : List of all users and fix unauthorized access.

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I've 2 requirement in QuickBlox JavaSript

1. I would like to get all users in one round rather than pagination approach, is that possible?
2. I see to get all users one has to be authorized from the application setting and I see 3 options available.

Allow to retrieve a list of users

Allow to retrieve other user's info

Require email confirmation (for application users)

And I think the right option is option 1, but will it be a security concern, can someone authorized access it?